# How to generate dummy variables based on multiple if criteria

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, dummy-variable, panel-data

I need to generate a few dummy variables in R and would like your input on this.

In the dataset, there are 10 observations per participant and each participant is allocated to one of the four treatments (1,2,3,4). The choice is to select either "1" or "2" in 10 tasks (taskno). Below are the observations.

```
+----+--------+---------+--------+
| id | taskno | treatno | choice |
+----+--------+---------+--------+
|  1 |      1 |       1 |      1 |
|  1 |      2 |       1 |      2 |
|  1 |      3 |       1 |      2 |
|  1 |      4 |       1 |      2 |
|  1 |      5 |       1 |      1 |
|  1 |      6 |       1 |      1 |
|  1 |      7 |       1 |      1 |
|  1 |      8 |       1 |      1 |
|  1 |      9 |       1 |      1 |
|  1 |     10 |       1 |      1 |
|  2 |      1 |       1 |      1 |
|  2 |      2 |       1 |      1 |
|  2 |      3 |       1 |      2 |
|  2 |      4 |       1 |      2 |
|  2 |      5 |       1 |      1 |
|  . |      . |       . |      . |
|  . |      . |       . |      . |
+----+--------+---------+--------+
```

Now, I would like to generate a dummy variable, let's call it dummy_1, such that once the participant selects the choice 2 and the treatno is 1, then the dummy_1 should be equal to 1 for all the remaining observations (taskno) for the same participant.

For instance, in the above example, participant 1 selected choice 2 in the second task. Now for rest of the observations (taskno: 3 to 10) for participant 1, the dummy_1 should be equal to 1 (irrespective of participant 1 choices in taskno 3 to 10). The same would apply to participant 2 and so on.

The output for the "dummy_1" should be:

```
+----+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| id | taskno | treatno | choice | dummy_1 |
+----+--------+---------+--------+---------+
|  1 |      1 |       1 |      1 |       0 |
|  1 |      2 |       1 |      2 |       0 |
|  1 |      3 |       1 |      2 |       1 |
|  1 |      4 |       1 |      2 |       1 |
|  1 |      5 |       1 |      1 |       1 |
|  1 |      6 |       1 |      1 |       1 |
|  1 |      7 |       1 |      1 |       1 |
|  1 |      8 |       1 |      1 |       1 |
|  1 |      9 |       1 |      1 |       1 |
|  1 |     10 |       1 |      1 |       1 |
|  2 |      1 |       1 |      1 |       0 |
|  2 |      2 |       1 |      1 |       0 |
|  2 |      3 |       1 |      2 |       0 |
|  2 |      4 |       1 |      2 |       1 |
|  2 |      5 |       1 |      1 |       1 |
|  . |      . |       . |      . |       . |
|  . |      . |       . |      . |       . |
+----+--------+---------+--------+---------+
```

Any help in this regard would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
your_data %>% group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(taskno) %>%
  mutate(dummy_1 = lag(as.integer(cumsum(choice == 2 & treatno == 1) > 0), default = 0))
```

Comment: thanks for this. What about the "treatno" variable? How would I be able to include that in your code?

Comment: Juste added `& treatno == 1`, that should do it.

Comment: thanks again. I tried this, but it didn't generate any "dummy_1" variable. I know the mutate command stores the variable virtually, however, I tried to save the modified excel file but the dummy_1 not found. Also, I ran the model and got error " object 'dummy_1' not found"

Comment: Save it in the object with `your_data <- your_data %>% ...`

Comment: It didn't work either. Perhaps, I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: I have finally made it work. The only problem is that the new data set didn't have the previous order of (id) and (taskno) and I have to manually sort the data